# Trouble uploading Spark AR effect to Instagram

Tags: facebook, spark-ar-studio

I am new to spark AR studio. I have built an effect which I am successfully able to submit to facebook and test it. But I have trouble submitting my effect to instagram.

I have linked my Instagram to Facebook as per the steps successfully. Then while submitting effect via Spark AR hub, it won't allow me to choose Effect Destination. It is locked as Facebook.

I have properly checked the linking as well as refreshed the Spark AR hub after linking the accounts and even tried log out login again post linking.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

Instagram access is still in beta and you have to apply for the beta on Spark AR website. If you're accepted, you are able to target Instagram along with Facebook as a target platform(s).